# VS Code can't connect to Google Chrome for html debug

Tags: html, visual-studio, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm having issues connecting to chrome through html vscode debug. each time I go to the run menu and click on **'start debugging'** or **'run without debugging'**, google chrome opens and shows new tab and not the file I'm debugging. When I return to vscode, I find out that the call stack is empty. I've also tried using a `launch.json` file. I haven't encountered this problem before. I was able to debug html with chrome without the chrome debugger extension(now deprecated). I don't know why I'm having these issues now.  Please can someone help me fix this issue? Thanks.

**NOTE: I recently uninstalled and installed the latest version of chrome and also installed chrome dev. I don't know if that has anything to do with this issue.**

Answer (score -1):

Open the html file and then Run-> "Launch Chrome".

lauch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [            
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9003
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${relativeFile}",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "port": 80,
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome",
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${relativeFile}",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome",
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am a VS newbie and have the same question. It used to work, but now Chrome wants to open http://localhost:8080 and fails. I don't know what's different compared to earlier successful attempts. The *Run* menu in my version of VS contains no *Launch Chrome*.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you could try using brackets - https://brackets.io/

Comment: It's a lot easier using the in built HTML preview feature in brackets, than struggling with VS Code